# javascript pattern for retrying failed calls and cancelling previous calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs, axios

I have a browser-based Javascript app (it's a Vue app, but that isn't necessarily relevant) that places calls to a server when the state changes.  If a call fails, I retry that call with exponential backoff.  If a call fails, and a later change in the state in the browser causes a second call, that second call's update to the server could later be overwritten by the retry of the first call.

This must be a common issue, but I can't seem to find any examples or plugins to handle this.  I'm using Axios currently, but am flexible in that choice.

Can anyone point me to a quick example that handles this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: found a good read here - https://medium.com/@benlesh/promise-cancellation-is-dead-long-live-promise-cancellation-c6601f1f5082

A nice strategy would be to stop repeating the calls of failure, if any, once a newer state has come and if a request isn't completed, yet, queue a new request using newer state.

Answer (score 3):

In RxJS you can use [`switchMap` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) that will cancel previous requests along with [some library for incremental backoff](https://github.com/alex-okrushko/backoff-rxjs) (or your own backoff implemntation)

Comment: Thanks @oles-savluk, I was fairly certain there was a way to do it with RxJS, but I was hoping to not add that as a dependency if there was another way.  I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if the community has other ideas.  If not, I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @user155995 , you might check sources of the linked lib -- it simply [uses](https://github.com/alex-okrushko/backoff-rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/retryBackoff.ts#L38) `.retryWhen` (with a bit of delaying and cancelling logic inside). So you could directly use it. Also, theres a good learnrxjs [example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html) displaying approach of using `.retryWhen` to make an exponential backoff.